# Cumulative Time a document was worked on

Tags: microsoft-office, metadata

Is there a way to find the cumulative time worked on a Word Document, Excel, or even a sent email?  (Not just the time stamp, but the time it was being edited or created?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a thing exists for Excel or sent emails, but Microsoft Word has `total editing time` as one of its properties (Select File -> Info to see it in Office 2010, earlier versions may differ).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the file > properties > "Details" tab.

Note that the time listed tends to shows the total amount of time that the document was left open, not actually spent changing things.